# Choose $a, b$ so that $\cos(x) - \frac{1+ax^2}{1+bx^2}$ would be as infinitely small as possible on ${x \to 0}$ using Taylor polynomial

Tags: real-analysis

$$\cos(x) - \frac{1+ax^2}{1+bx^2} \text{ on } x \to 0$$

If $\displaystyle \cos(x) = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \cdots $

Then we should choose $a, b$ in a such way that it's Taylor series is close to this.

However, I'm not sure how to approach this. I tried to take several derivates of second term to see its value on $x_0 = 0$, but it becomes  complicated and I don't see general formula for $n$-th derivative at point zero to find $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I'm guessing this would mean $a$ and $b$ should be so chosen that for any other pair of numbers $c,d$, there is some interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ such that for $x$ in that interval $\cos x- (1+ax^2)/(1+bx^2)$ is closer to $0$ than is $\cos x - (1+cx^2)/(1+dx^2).$ Which interval that is would depend on $c$ and $d. \qquad$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant $\qquad$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quick-and-dirty method:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \frac{1 + a x^2}{1 + bx^2} &= (1 + a x^2) \left( 1 - b x^2 + b^2 x^4 - b^3 x^6 + \cdots \right) \\&= 1 - (b - a) x^2 + (b^2 - ab) x^4 - (b^3 - a b^2) x^6 + \cdots
\end{align*}
We want $b - a = \frac{1}{2}$ and $b (b-a) = \frac{1}{24}$, so that (at least) the first three terms in the Taylor series of $f(x)$ and $\cos x$ agree.  This implies that $b = \frac{1}{12}$ and $a = -\frac{5}{12}$;  with this choice, we have
$$
f(x) = \frac{1 - \frac{5}{12} x^2}{1 + \frac{1}{12} x^2} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} - \frac{x^6}{288} + \cdots
$$
which agrees with $\cos x$ up to the $\mathcal{O}(x^6)$ term.

Comment: $+1.$ I had just reached the conclusion that $b=a+\frac12$ when this got posted. $\qquad$

Comment: PS: Maybe you should consider up-voting the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Notice that, by its Taylor expansion, $\big(\cos(x)-1\big)\to0$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: So you think that $a$ should equal $b$ and that's the solution? Or they should equal to zero? That sounds too simple.

Comment: If I understood correctly your question, yes. You could take $a=b=0$, for instance.

Comment: the thing is that task implies  **infinitely small as possible** .

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for any $a,b$

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+ax^2}{1+bx^2}=1$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to0}\cos(x)=1$$

So regardless of $a,b$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to0}\cos(x)-\frac{1+ax^2}{1+bx^2}=1-1=0$$

Comment: I think this misses the point of the question. It wasn't expressed very precisely, but it seems something different from this must have been intended. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, precisely task says "infinitely small value of the highest order", but it is not in English, so I translated it how I understood it.  That among all functions  this should be smallest given a and b on x approaching 0. As I understand, choosing function which has zero limit doesn't exactly solves this.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is

$$\cos(x)-\frac{a}{b}-\frac{1-\frac{a}{b} }{  bx^2+1  }$$

$$=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{a}{b}-1+\frac{a}{b}+bx^2-ax^2-b(b-a)x^4+x^4\epsilon(x).$$

thus, we need
$b-a=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $b(b-a)=-\frac{1}{24}$.

which gives

$b=\frac{1}{12}$ and $a=\frac{7}{12}$.

Answer (score 0):

Another slight variation:
$$1 + ax^2\approx (1+bx^2)\cos x = 1 + (b - 1/2)x^2 + (1/24 - b/2)x^4 + \cdots$$
$$a = b - \frac12;$$
$$0 = \frac1{24}-\frac{b}2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note you just need to compute the Taylor expansion of
\begin{align}
g(x)&=\cos x+bx^2\cos x-1-ax^2 \\[6px]
&=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}
+bx^2-\frac{bx^4}{2!}+\frac{bx^6}{4!}-1-ax^2+o(x^6)\\[6px]
&=\left(-\frac{1}{2}+b-a\right)x^2+
  \left(\frac{1}{24}-\frac{b}{2}\right)x^4+
  \left(-\frac{1}{6!}+\frac{b}{4!}\right)x^6+o(x^6)
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
\begin{cases}
a-b=-\dfrac{1}{2} \\[6px]
b=\dfrac{1}{12}
\end{cases}
$$